# firebase custom token header throws error while deploying

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication, digital-ocean

I had this MERN app with firebase authentication working perfectly. It uses a custom token to authenticate users in the backend(node.js).

decode id token is using this statement:
`const header = req.headers?.authorization;`

But it throws the following error while deploying it to digitalocean:

```
/home/admin-nithur/app/authenticateToken.js:8
  const header = req.headers?.authorization;
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/admin-nithur/app/server.js:9:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Why is this happening? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional chaining (property?.otherProperty) is only implemented in Node v14 and upwards, you are probably using an older version.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the ecmaVersion in your eslint config to 2020.

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  }
}
```

Also make sure you are using Node 14.

Comment: Currently, I don't have an eslint config file. should I add one?